# How to make use of structure in another class?

Tags: c++, class, struct, fstream

Okay hello guys, i have a problem with my current assignment

i have 2 classes, namely employee class, and a gm class.

in employee class, there is a structure that i used, namely

```
struct eInfo
{
    char username [80];
    char password [80];
    int eid;
};
```

however, in my gm class, i have functions that rely on the struct in employee class. for example,

```
void addEmployee(fstream&, int, eInfo&);
void delEmployee(fstream&, int, eInfo&);
void editEmployee(fstream&, int, eInfo&);
```

how am i suppose to make use of that?

what i have tried is redeclaring a

```
struct eInfo
{
    char username [80];
    char password [80];
    int eid;
};
```

inside the gm class. but that does not work well. No syntax error, but when im using

fstream afile;
afile.open("EmployeeInfo.dat", ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);

the file turns out to empty itself.

any idea how to fix this ??

Comment: Why don't you make the second class a **friend** of the first class?

Comment: Why don't you take the `eInfo` struct out of the class?

Answer (score 0):

If the struct `eInfo` is declared **inside** `employe` then you should refer to it as `employe::eInfo` when you are outside `employe`. If you redeclare it inside `gm` then the compiler will consider that `employe::eInfo` and `gm::eInfo` are two different classes.

Answer (score 0):

Declare eInfo in the the appropriate header file and then include that header file in your gm class. To create a struct, use this syntax. The variable names are just fillers for whatever you happen to use when you create the struct.

```
eInfo myStruct = {theUsername, thePassword, theEid};
```